# How to speed up scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I need to collect a lot(really a lot) of data for statistics, all the necessary information is in `<script type="application/ld+json"></script>`
and I wrote scrapy parser (script inside html) under it, but parsing is very slow (about 3 pages per second). Is there any way to speed up the process? Ideally I would like to see 10+ pages per second

#spider.py:

```
import scrapy
import json

class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrape'
    start_urls = [
                 about 10000 urls
                 ]

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.css('script[type="application/ld+json"]::text').extract_first())
        name = data['name']
        image = data['image']
        path = response.css('span[itemprop="name"]::text').extract()
        yield {
            'name': name,
            'image': image,
            'path': path
        }
        return
```

#settings.py:

```
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.33
DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
   'Accept-Language': 'en',
}
EXTENSIONS = {
  'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
}
AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False
LOG_ENABLED = False
```

My PC specs:

16GB ram, i5 2400, ssd, 1gb ethernet

#Edited

Comment: Are you using Splash with this crawler?

Comment: No, only scrapy. because <script> in html I don't need splash

Comment: Can you try to disable Splash middleware then? Remove `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` and bump `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` a bit.

Comment: Though 3 pages per second is already quite a bit. That's 180requests/min and you'll probably get banned for going much more than that.

Comment: I collect statistics from fairly large sites (some even international ones) so I don't think it will be a big problem.

Comment: How about doing them in parallel?

Comment: You mean run the program in several terminals? Or should I parallelize the program itself into several threads?

Comment: I'm new to scrapy so I don't know how to implement the second variant...

Comment: But now I'm seeing that after a certain period of time the program stops (and the scrapy bench starts outputting `0 crawled pages (0 pages/min)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**settings.py**

```py
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 30
RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY = True

REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE = 128
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 256
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 256
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 256

AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 1
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 0.25
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 128
AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = True

RETRY_ENABLED = True
RETRY_TIMES = 3
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504, 400, 401, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 429]

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware': 80,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 120,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware': 130,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware': 900,
    'scraper.middlewares.ScraperDownloaderMiddleware': 1000
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I'm sorry I didn't answer for a long time.

Comment: I set up your code, download 'scraper' and 'scrapy_fake_useragent' but then I got a error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scraper.middlewares'`
. Can you please tell me what a 'scraper' is and how to solve this bug(didn't find any information about it in the internet =(  )

Comment: I tried to run the code on your settings (without 'scraper.middlewares.ScraperDownloaderMiddleware': 1000) and 50 links later (I think) was banned and just get `DEBUG: Retrying <GET "url"> (failed 1/2/3 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting "url" took longer than 30.0 seconds..` =(

Comment: Try to increase ```DOWNLOAD_DELAY``` to an optimum value after doing some trials.

Comment: If delay becomes a bottleneck, what are the advantages of increasing CONCURRENT and AUTOTHROTTLE? Does DOWNLOADER MIDDLEWARES also make sense?

Comment: the delay became the same as it was before.